# How i can find the word in this query params?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm trying to make a query that filters by a string param with this format:

```
filter: (status~contains~false~and~username~contains~'admin')
```

So, i need to make a `search(`) in this `request.input('filter')` and search the word after the contains to make my query. I'm with difficulty to make the regex (i don't know if i really need a regex)

Something like:

```
 if(request.input('filter').search('regex??'))
            queryUsers.where('username', 'like', '%'+request.input('username')+'%')
```

**Tried:**

```
if(filter.search("username")){
            let userName = filter.search(/?<=username~contains~).*$/g).replace("'", "")
            console.log(userName)
            //queryUsers.where('username', 'like', '%'+request.input('username')+'%')
}
```

But i receive:

> Invalid regular expression: /?<=username~contains~).*$/: Nothing to
>   repeat

Answer (score 0):

No need to use regular expression you can run like query as below - 
`Database.from('users').whereRaw('username Like ?', ['%'+request.input('username')+'%'])`

Comment: if i do a console.log(request.input('username')) i receive: undefined.
username is in request.input('filter') parameter, that contains the string that i put on the question

Comment: then change request.input('username') to request.input('filter')
rest query would remain same

Comment: tried queryUsers.whereRaw('username like ?', ['%'+request.input('filter')+'%']) but don't return anything.

Comment: Can you just check if, records are present with "admin"

Comment: then there is just one prob. that you are missing await